# Height is 100% of parent but still overflowing

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I am making a web gallery. I have function that rotates the image when user press R or click rotate button. But i am having difficulty maintaining aspect ratio and rotating image.

At first when the image load i calculate it dimensions using javascript.
Below function is responsible for the dimensions.
It takes image original width and height and its parent width and height and rotation (cause when an element is rotated it's width becomes it's height and it's height becomes it's width);
And then calculate new width and height according to rotation so the image will take 100% width or height of it's parent element while maintaining it's aspect ratio.  (don't get confused with screenHeight and width these are parentWidth and height not screen).

```
function calculateNewDimensions(
  imgWidth,
  imgHeight,
  screenWidth,
  screenHeight,
  rotation,
) {
  // Returning Variables
  let newWidth = null;
  let newHeight = null;
  // Given Data
  const oldAspectRatio = rotation === 90 || rotation === 270
    ? imgWidth / imgHeight
    : imgHeight / imgWidth;
  const rotatedAspectRatio = rotation === 90 || rotation === 270
    ? imgHeight / imgWidth
    : imgWidth / imgHeight;
  const screenAspectRatio = screenWidth / screenHeight;
  // Solution
  if (oldAspectRatio > 1) {
    console.log('Image was landscape before');
    // Image is wide
    if (screenAspectRatio > 1) {
      console.log('screen is wide');
      // Screen is wide
      if (rotation === 90 || rotation === 270) {
        newWidth = screenHeight;
        newHeight = screenHeight * rotatedAspectRatio;
      } else {
        newHeight = screenHeight;
        newWidth = screenHeight * rotatedAspectRatio;
      }
    } else {
      console.log('Screen is portrait');
      // Screen is Portrait
      /* Now comparing aspect Ratio to find best fit
       * Should the width fit or height
       */
      if (rotatedAspectRatio < screenAspectRatio) {
        console.log('new ratio is less wider than screen');
        // Image height greater than screen
        if (rotation === 90 || rotation === 270) {
          newWidth = screenHeight;
          newHeight = screenHeight * rotatedAspectRatio;
        } else {
          newHeight = screenHeight;
          newWidth = screenHeight * rotatedAspectRatio;
        }
      } else {
        console.log('new ratio is wider than screen\'s');
        // Image height less than screen
        if (rotation === 90 || rotation === 270) {
          newHeight = screenWidth;
          newWidth = screenWidth / rotatedAspectRatio;
        } else {
          newWidth = screenWidth;
          newHeight = screenWidth / rotatedAspectRatio;
        }
      }
    }
  } else {
    console.log('Image was potrait before');
    // Image was Portrait Before
    if (screenAspectRatio > 1) {
      console.log('parent is wide');
      // Screen is Wide
      /*
       * Now comparing aspect Ratio to find best fit
       * Should the width fit or height
       */
      if (rotatedAspectRatio > screenAspectRatio) {
        console.log('New Ratio is wider than screen');
        // New width is greater than screen's
        if (rotation === 0 || rotation === 180) {
          newWidth = screenWidth;
          newHeight = screenWidth / rotatedAspectRatio;
        } else {
          newWidth = screenHeight;
          newHeight = screenWidth / rotatedAspectRatio;
        }
      } else {
        console.log('New Ratio is less wider than parent');
        // New Height is greater than screen's
        if (rotation === 90 || rotation === 270) {
          newWidth = screenHeight;
          newHeight = screenHeight * rotatedAspectRatio;
        } else {
          console.log('Rotation is 0 or 180');
          newHeight = screenHeight;
          newWidth = screenHeight * rotatedAspectRatio;
        }
      }
    } else {
      console.log('Screen is portrait');
      // Screen is Portrait
      if (rotation === 90 || rotation === 270) {
        newHeight = screenWidth;
        newWidth = screenWidth * rotatedAspectRatio;
      } else {
        newWidth = screenWidth;
        newHeight = screenWidth / rotatedAspectRatio;
      }
    }
  }
  return { width: newWidth, height: newHeight };
}
```

[Image showing when the image first's load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHUhQ.png)

Then when user presses R or click rotate button i increment the rotation by an angle of 90 using `element.style,transform`. Call the above function again.  Get's the new width and height of rotated image and use's `element.style.width` and `element.style.height` to change the rotated image dimensions. If the image is landscape it get's rotated at all angles without strechting and overflowing but as you can see in the above image-link that the image is portrait so i rotate the image set its width to parent height and calculate new width but it's overflowing and i don't know why

[image showing how the image in gallery is overflowing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvESd.png)

As you can see in the above link the image width is 100% of it's parent height and and height is also less than width of parent. But still it's overflowing and have empty space around on y-axis of parent. If you see in the console. The function is working fine first it logs that image was portrait before then it logs that parent is wide meaning landscape which is screen. and then that the image is less wider than parent so i give it 100% height of it's parent.

Now here's something interesting. Currently i am calculating the image new height (cause the image is rotated and it's height is on the x-axis) by multiplying the screenHeight (rotated image width) with aspect ratio.

```
console.log('New Ratio is less wider than parent');
// New Height is greater than screen's
if (rotation === 90 || rotation === 270) {
  newWidth = screenHeight;
  newHeight = screenHeight * rotatedAspectRatio;
} else {
  console.log('Rotation is 0 or 180');
  newHeight = screenHeight;
  newWidth = screenHeight * rotatedAspectRatio;
}
```

If i calculate it not by multiplying but by dividing. The image stop's overflowing but become distored or strechy.

[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Avyzg.png)

incase you think this is css issue let me clear you its not the image css is below

```
#active-image-wrapper > img {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    transform-origin: center;
    transition: all ease 0.2s;
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

Any suggestion how can i resolve this issue?

Comment: It seems the problem is not related to the image resizing at all, instead its parent container's height does not follow along the height calculation and causes the overflows.

Comment: i think it's related to transform origin

Comment: Can you like took a look. i need this project deliver today and i have'nt fixed this issue yet. i am trying and trying but all in vain

Comment: Without having access to your code it won't be possible to fix the issue. What you could try for now as a nasty workaround (while searching for the actual problem), you could hide the scrollbars from the container with the yellow outline by adding `overflow: hidden;` to it.